# Question concerning the weighted least squares

Tags: multiple-regression, weighted-regression, generalized-least-squares

If the weighted least squares estimators are equal to the ordinary (unweighted) least squares estimators when when the errors have common variance $σ^2$ would it mean that the model given by the weighted least squares is homoscedastic and that the weights are equal to 1?

Comment: Please explain what you have in mind by "weighted least squares estimators."  It sounds like you might be considering some procedure in which the weights are estimated from the data (but that's not the usual meaning).

Comment: I think you are asking (?) what happens if a linear model has errors with constant variance yet you would be estimating the parameters of the model using weighted least squares? If that is the case, you should know that in weighted least squares the weights are typically supplied by the analyst, rather than estimated by the model. Also, it wouldn't be necessary to fit a model with unequal weights if the data didn't suggest a need for it.